# Accesing a single Set as value of a Map

Tags: java, collections, syntax, dictionary

I need to display a value from a key-value pair of a Map when the value is a set. The key which value will be displayed can be specified as argument of method.  I am not sure what the syntax is to access this. I did it successfully when it was a string.

Can anyone make any suggestsion of the below:

```
HashMap<String, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
Set<Integer> theValues = new Set<>();

public void mapValue(String aString)
{
    if(map.containsKey(aString))
    { 

      System.out.println ("The value of the set is " + theValues  ); 
      // what can go here to show the elements of the set that 
      // is the value map given the key?
    }


}
```

Comment: Do you need to whole set for a given key?

Comment: `map.get(aString)` returns the value associated with the key. And in this case, the value is a `Set<Integer>`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need something like this to iterate over the Set values for each Map key:

```
HashMap<String, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String,Set<Integer>>();
Set<Integer> theValues = new HashSet<Integer>();

public void mapValue(String aString) {
    if(map.containsKey(aString)) {
        System.out.println ("The values of the set is:");
        Set<Integer> set = map.get(aString);
        for (Integer i: set)
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```